# SQL select multiple columns to multiple variables using where

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a simple table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [accounting].[ExtractControl](
    [SourceSchema] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SourceTable] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [SourceDatabase] [varchar](50) NOT NULL)
```

I would like to select *SourceDatabase* using *SourceSchema* and *SourceTable* values

Currently I am doing with multiple queries as follows

```
Select @s1 = SourceDatabase from accounting.ExtractControl where SourceSchema = 'xxx' and SourceTable = 'xxx'
Select @s2 = SourceDatabase from accounting.ExtractControl where SourceSchema = 'yyy' and SourceTable = 'yyy'
Select @s3 = SourceDatabase from accounting.ExtractControl where SourceSchema = 'xxx' and SourceTable = 'yyy'
```

I do believe that this can be done in more elegant ways! Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you find not elegant with your current solution?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I am querying the database 3 times to return 3 variables, I am thinking that maybe its possible to return all 3 variables using 1 query against the Db.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for something like this?

```
select SourceDatabase from accounting.ExtractControl
where SourceSchema in ('xxx', 'yyy') and SourceTable in ('xxx', 'yyy');
```

This will return the `SourceDatabase` where the `SourceSchema` is either 'xxx' or 'yyy' and the `SourceTable` is either 'xxx' or 'yyy'.

Comment: Hi Daniel

It would indeed return SourceDatabase but I want them to be stored in different variables depending on SourceSchema and SourceTable

For eg. s1 should be when SourceSchema and SourceTable are both 'xxx'
s2 -> when both are 'yyy'... etc etc

Comment: If you actually need three different variables, go with your current solution.

Comment: @dopplesoldner: Agree with Daniel: if you want the three results in three distinct variables, stay with your current solution. However, if you elaborate more on how exactly you are going to use those variables, it *may* turn out there's a better way (or it may not).

Answer (score 1):

option with one query

```
SELECT @s1 = MAX(CASE WHEN SourceSchema = 'xxx' and SourceTable = 'xxx' THEN SourceDatabase END),
       @s2 = MAX(CASE WHEN SourceSchema = 'yyy' and SourceTable = 'yyy' THEN SourceDatabase END),
       @s3 = MAX(CASE WHEN SourceSchema = 'xxx' and SourceTable = 'yyy' THEN SourceDatabase END)
FROM accounting.ExtractControl
```

Demo on [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75a58/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from accounting.ExtractControl
where SourceSchema = 'xxx' or SourceSchema = 'yyy'
```

Comment: Hi Mert
I want them to be stored in different variables depending on SourceSchema and SourceTable 

For eg. s1 should be when SourceSchema and SourceTable are both 'xxx' s2 -> when both are 'yyy'... etc etc

Comment: I dont think there is better way then. you may select like this and linq in your code.

Answer (score 0):

what about this Query...

```
select SourceDatabase
from accounting.ExtractControl
where SourceSchema in ('xxx', 'yyy')
      and SourceTable in ('xxx', 'yyy')
      and SourceTable = SourceSchema
```

i did not tried this but i think this is what you required

Comment: if you want each cell value to different varriable then go with cursor now